# DI in Zend Framework 2. How to make cyclic dependancy?

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

How to implement this:

```
<?php
class MyClass1
{
     public function __construct(MyClass2 $objClass2)
     {
          $this->objClass2 = $objClass2;
      }
}

class MyClass2
{
     public function setClass1(MyClass1 $objClass1)
    {
          $this->objClass1 = $objClass1;
     }
}
?>
```

I mean I need to create a `MyClass2` object, put it into `MyClass1` constructor and then I need `MyClass1` object to be put into `MyClass2` object that was created before via setClass1 method. Is it possible to do in DI config in ZendFramework?

Comment: That sounds like a horror scenario. The question should be, how to avoid cyclic dependency.

Comment: @markus For example, there are classes Mother and Child. A child knows his/her mother, and a mother knows her children. How to avoid cyclic dependency in this case?

Comment: A real world analogy is not an argument for an anti-pattern. Tell me a real programming necessity for this and I'll try to tell you how you can solve it better.

Comment: @markus-tharkun For example, a forum script. I have PostsRepository class with method getPost and UsersRepository class with method getUserProfileInfo.
Those methods should return objects with all nececcary data: posts should have authors (User objects) and ProfileInfo should have count of posts.
So, PostRepository and UsersRepository should have links to each other.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want this! If you injected Class2 into Class1 you already have access to it, by using `$class1->class2->somethingSomething();`, or you can retrieve it by `$class->getClass2();` and so on... I don't know what your actual scenario is, but when you have cyclic dependecy, something's gone awry.